# Anaconda import existing virtualenv

Tags: python, import, virtualenv, anaconda

I want to import an existing virtual env, which I created using `anaconda` into another anaconda installation on a different distribution.

I've tried creating a new one using the following command in the directory of the venv copied from the other distribution:

```
conda create -p . python=3.4
```

That results in:

```
Error: prefix already exists: /home/xiaolong/development/blog
```

But anaconda does not know that, when I ask it to list all existing venvs:

```
conda info --envs
```

This results in:

```
# conda environments:
#
firstenv                 /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/firstenv
gtkplus-tool             /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/gtkplus-tool
testenv                  /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/testenv
tkxld                    /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/tkxld
wxpython-phoenix-tutorial     /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3/envs/wxpython-phoenix-tutorial
root                  *  /home/xiaolong/development/anaconda3
```

This list is missing my copied venv. How do I add it to that list, so that I can then use `source activate blog` for example?

Answer (score -1):

`-p .` cannot work because the directory must not exist already.

You probably want your env in `/home/xiaolong/development/blog/env` or something similar. So just do `conda create -p ./env python=3.4`.