# Creating virtual environment using environment.yml in miniconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am trying to create virtual environment using environment.yml in miniconda (Where environment.yml contains a list of all dependecies.) using the following command:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

but I get this error (this is entire output)

```
Error: prefix already exists: /home/danish/miniconda3/envs/venv
```

Can someone help me correcting the error?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is that the entire output?

Comment: yeah , thats the entire output

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055352/anaconda-import-existing-virtualenv help you at all?

Comment: I have gone through this earlier , but didnot help :(

Comment: sorry I'm not sure how to help (other then the upvote and slight editing) as I'm not familiar with anaconda, I wish you luck though!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The environment.yml specifies that the name of the environment is `venv` at the top of your file -- i.e.

```
name: venv
```

But that environment already exists (you can see it via `conda env list`).  The solution here is to change the name in the environment.yml or use a different name when you are creating the environment.  Example:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml -n new-env-name
```

Where the `new-env-name` is an environment name you haven't used yet.